# How to calculate the spin of atomic nuclei?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy, spin

I have recently been learning about nuclear magnetic resonance spectroscopy. It is mentioned that the spin of the $^{1}$H nucleus is $\frac{1}{2}\ $and the spin of the $^{2}$H nucleus is $1$. This made me think that this likely has something to do with the number of protons and neutrons and this is indeed the case. [This site](https://teaching.shu.ac.uk/hwb/chemistry/tutorials/molspec/nmr1.htm)  reveals that:

> 1. If the number of neutrons and the number of protons are both even, then the nucleus has no spin.
> 2. If the number of neutrons plus the number of protons is odd, then the nucleus has a half-integer spin (i.e. $\frac{1}{2}\ $, $\frac{3}{2}\ $, $\frac{5}{2}\ $).
> 3. If the number of neutrons and the number of protons are both odd, then the nucleus has an integer spin (i.e. $1$, $2$, $3$).

However, I was unable to find a site which stated the exact formula needed to determine the spins of atomic nuclei. Thus, I would like to ask if such a formula exists or is the determination of nuclear spin only done through experiment?

Comment: There is no formula.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So the nuclear spin of an atomic nucleus can only be known through experimental means?

Comment: @Ivan what happens if we try to use nuclear shells?

Comment: @OscarLanzi It works poorly. The system is extremely computationally complicated and involves relativistic effects and strong spin-orbit coupling. Add that nuclon-nuclon interactions are a shadow of quark-quark interactions and things become... sketchy.

Comment: I'm afraid you could as well ask how to get spin of arbitrary molecule and it's too broad. Also are you interested in spins of **ground states**? Nuclei can be excited just as molecules can be.

Comment: @Mithoron I am mainly interested in the nuclear spins. However, if you would like to include how to obtain spins in general in your answer, I would be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: By checking out table list like http://easyspin.org/documentation/isotopetable.html